# Using Linked List to remove items

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am working on this code to remove items from a linked list.
So say the list is {3,3,7,8,4,3,0,4} .. And I want to remove all the 3's 
My output should be 7, 8, 4, 0, 4

The code I have created is only removing one of the threes, and not them all.

```
public void eraseNumber(Object x)
{
   if (start == null)
     return;
   else if (start.data.equals(x)) {
     start = start.next;
     count--;
   }
  else {
    Node ptr;
    for (ptr = start; ptr.next != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
      if (ptr.next.data.equals(x)) {
        ptr.next = ptr.next.next;
        count--;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

The out put I am getting for this code is 3, 7, 8, 4, 3, 0, 4.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Is `Object` really the most specific you can / want to use as input for your method? I ask, as the method is named `eraseNumber` that is way more specific than `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply `return`ing from the method if the number to be removed happens to be at the `start` or a match is found in your `for` loop. You would need to remove the `if-else` to let the program run your `for` loop and remove the `return;` to let you iterate over all the list elements.

Also note the use of `while` loop to remove all the matching numbers at the `start` of your list.

```
while (start != null && start.data.equals(x)) { // use while here
 start = start.next;
 count--;
}

for (Node ptr = start; ptr != null && ptr.next != null;) {
  if (ptr.next.data.equals(x)) {
    ptr.next = ptr.next.next;
    count--;
  } else // conditional increment
    ptr = ptr.next;
}
```

Comment: Using the while loop in the bottom half of your code, it seems you will definitely raise a NullPointerException.

Comment: @TheMorph Thanks for the catch. I've done away with the `while` altogether. Didn't like the *loop in a loop* approach while still eliminating consecutive matches as before.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is `if-elseIf` construct, the code will enter the first `elseif` and then will exit the method without entering the final `else` .

Use a while or for loop to iterate through the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The return in your if statement makes your code exit the if statement and the for loop, if anything is found. So the first time you find a 3 you exit the for loop. remove the return and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ravi allready told you a way , im not sure but i think u should also replace if with while

```
if (start == null)
 return;
while (start.data.equals(x)) { // use while here
 start = start.next;
 count--;
}
Node ptr;
for (ptr = start; ptr.next != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
  while (ptr.next != null && ptr.next.data.equals(x)) { //while to remove a sequence of 3's
    ptr.next = ptr.next.next;
    count--;
    // return; don't exit here
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the while loop in the bottom half of your code, it seems you will definitely raise a NullPointerException.

Comment: thats true, i added a 2nd condition to the loop

Comment: You duplicated some of the functionality of the for-loop with your while loop. You don't really need it. `if` works perfectly fine.

Comment: no! a sequence of 43333 would would result in 4X3X3, because it would just check if next is a three and replace it with next.next, and then set ptr to next, which might be a 3 again -> error

Comment: i would rate ur comment now but i cant :)

Comment: When you look at my solution you will understand why i was confused. I am used to only look at the current node and remembering the last one. ;)

Comment: in genaral i would use a iterator class, whith remove function, little more code but is more flexible

Comment: Totally agree with this, but OP might not have the knowledge yet.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple things:

First of all your last return statement will make the method return the first time you find an element that equals `x`. You should remove it. This is one cause of error.

I think you wanted to use a while loop here so to find every `x` on the beginning of `start`?

```
else if (start.data.equals(x)) {
   start = start.next;
   count--;
}
```

Now look at what happens if `start` only consists of one element, and this one element is also equal to `x`? You will receive an exception here

```
for (ptr = start; ptr.next != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
```

as you would call `null.next` that doesn't exist. Actually it would be even worse with a while-loop, but fortunately a null test will help. ;)

Now to more cosmetic things:

This

```
if (start == null)
     return;
else if (start.data.equals(x)) {
```

could be written as

```
if (start == null)
     return;
if (start.data.equals(x)) {
```

by omitting the `else` it becomes a bit easier to read, even though it will behave the same.

---

This is what I would write:

```
public void eraseNumber(Object x) {

   while (start != null && start.data.equals(x) {
      start = start.next;
      count--;
   }

   Node lastNode = start;
   Node currentNode = start;

   while (currentNode != null) {
      if (currentNode.data.equals(x)) {
         lastNode.next = currentNode.next;
         count--;
      } else {
         lastNode = currentNode;
      }
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
   }

}
```

You may want to substitute `Object` with something more specific.

Note: I had to fix a bug in my implementation missing the first x in the linked list.